# Отлавливать изменение изображений в галерее

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть автоматическая галерея(слайд шоу)на главной странице сайта, необходимо изменять текст в блоке параллельно с изображением. Подскажите как отследить изменение в блоке с изображением?

Comment: Какой плагин используете?

Comment: slideshowify если не ошибаюсь

Comment: В этом есть возможность вешаться на события смены слайда (http://slideshowify.com/ см раздел про хуки)